# Jmeter 5 set client tls certificate not work

Tags: java, ssl, https, client-certificates, jmeter-5.0

I've struggled one day but without luck. Googling can find few but often outdated answers.

My goal is using jmeter **built in** elements to send https request **with client certificate**. Think of some oauth server that validates the client certificate other than password.

I know writing my own plugin, or use some beanshell, etc, is possible. but I searched and found jmeter has built in [Keystore Config Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Keystore_Configuration) so I decide to have a try.

---

First I setup my mock server, https://leiyang.icu:5001/home, an asp.net core website, which validates the clients has sent a certificate. It simply accepts `GET` at path `/home`, with optional query parameter `location`. If client sends request with any certificate, it will response the `location` value and the client certificate information as string, otherwise connection will abort(TODO: response some friendly message instead).

This is a working python client script to validate the server:

```
import requests

resp = requests.get('https://leiyang.icu:5001/home',
                    # if not specify cert, connection will be aborted by the server
                    cert=('pathto/any.crt',
                          'pathto/any.key'),
                    params={'location': 'fromrequests'}
                    )
print(resp.text)
```

output:

> location=fromrequests cert=[Subject]   CN={domain of client}
>
> [Issuer]   CN=Encryption Everywhere DV TLS CA - G1,
> OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
> ... and several other lines about the certificate

---

Now my steps to use jmeter as client:

1. Download [jmeter 5.4.1](https://mirrors.bfsu.edu.cn/apache//jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.4.1.zip) on my win10 with jdk 11, unzip.
2. In `bin` folder,
   2.1 edit `system.properties`, set
   `javax.net.ssl.keyStore={mykeypath}`
   `javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword={thepwd}`
   2.2 edit `jmeter.properties` set
   `https.use.cached.ssl.context=false`
3. Launch jmeter GUI, new a plan, add `csv data set config`,  `key store config`, `http request sampler`, `view results tree element` as the manuals guide. (It's to lengthy to put all details here, but I'll put some runtime logs later).
4. Run the sampler. All requests failed(*org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: leiyang.icu:5001 failed to respond*) due to certificate issue. If change server code to not check certificate, then all requests pass.

---

Now some investigations:

- Jmeter log.

  021-07-07 22:31:21,481 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!

  2021-07-07 22:31:21,482 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []

  2021-07-07 22:31:21,484 INFO o.a.j.c.KeystoreConfig: Configuring Keystore with (preload: 'True', startIndex: 0, endIndex: -1, clientCertAliasVarName: 'cv')

  2021-07-07 22:31:21,485 INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: JmeterKeyStore Location: C:/Users/myname/Downloads/cert/cert.p12 type pkcs12

  2021-07-07 22:31:21,485 INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: KeyStore created OK

  2021-07-07 22:31:21,485 WARN o.a.j.u.SSLManager: No password provided, and no GUI present so cannot prompt

  2021-07-07 22:31:21,494 INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: Total of 1 aliases loaded OK from keystore C:/Users/myname/Downloads/cert/cert.p12

  2021-07-07 22:31:21,494 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)

  2021-07-07 22:31:21,524 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group

  2021-07-07 22:31:21,524 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group.

  2021-07-07 22:31:21,524 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error

  2021-07-07 22:31:21,524 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 delayedStart=false

  2021-07-07 22:31:21,525 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1

  2021-07-07 22:31:21,526 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started

  2021-07-07 22:31:21,528 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1

  2021-07-07 22:31:21,528 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Stored: t.csv

  2021-07-07 22:31:21,892 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1

  2021-07-07 22:31:21,892 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1

  2021-07-07 22:31:21,893 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test

  2021-07-07 22:31:21,893 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Close: t.csv

  2021-07-07 22:31:21,893 INFO o.a.j.c.KeystoreConfig: Destroying Keystore

  2021-07-07 22:31:21,893 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
- In Key Store, I set the `Variable name holding certificate alias` field to `cv`, and in the `http sampler/parames` tab I added  parameter `location=${cv}` with same variable name as cert alias `cv`, and in `results tree/request` tab, I can see `GET https://leiyang.icu:5001/home?location=myalias`, which means the variable is correctly assigned.
- I had use `keytool -v -list -storetype pkcs12 -keystore mycert.p12` to check the alias, is same as that in jmeter variable(`cv`)
- In `http sampler/parames/sdvanced` tab, I have chosen `implementation` as `HttpClient4`.
- The log doesn't contain any information about the certificate is actually used by http client, and even if put some wrong alias to the variable, nothing different happens in log.

---

So what's the problem, am I miss something? Could you give me any diagnosis suggestions?

---

**Update**:
I just tried exactly same steps with jmeter 4.0(with java8), and it's working!
So I doubt whether this is an issue of jmeter 5(with jdk11).